# Rails : simplify a complex Deployment Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, setup-deployment

Heres the overview. I have developed a ruby on rails app on my local MacBook Pro machine using the standard webBrick server that comes with rails. All assets are in place and all gems are installed in the application.
I have an account with 1&1 and they have a dedicated L2 Linux server that caters for Ruby on Rails apps.
What I want to know is how do I, from what I have now, a fully working rails app in development mode on my local machine transfer/deploy this to the L2 Linux Server. I.e. what details/credentials/software would I need to complete this? My rails app uses a MYSQL database. Rails version is 3.2.8 and ruby version is Ruby 1.8.7

I hope this question is completely understandable.

Answer (score 1):

While it depends on your app, the main dependencies are: web server, database and username, and probably access to source control.

You'll need to initialize the environment:

- set up web server connection to Rails, e.g. Apache or Nginx and Passenger
- create a deploy user
- install MySQL and set a password
- set up ssh
- connect to source control
- and so on

Then change various files in `config` and `config/environments` to use these values and check them in.  Then you'll need pull your code from source control, run the rake:db_setup command and perhaps others.

I encourage you to use capistrano to do deployments -- while not necessary, it is widely used for this purpose, and highly configurable.

Check out [this page on Railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=similar) which provides a lot of information about this topic.